# Java selenium - Second method is not included in test

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm new in automation testing so I would really appreciate your help. When I run the test only firs method (mainPage) is executed. If I add @Test prefix before second method (monitors), test will be run in a new window and I want test to continue in same window after first method ends.

```java
public class comtradeShop {

    WebDriver driver;
    String URL = "https://www.ctshop.rs/";

    @BeforeMethod
    public void init() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver_91.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(URL);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    // public void quit(){}

    @Test
    public void mainPage() throws InterruptedException {
        WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".am-opener.sharkskin-collapse"));


        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sharkskin-megamenu.megamenu-v.megamenu-am>li:nth-child(6)")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement popup = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".soundest-form-background-image-wrapper"));
        if (popup.isDisplayed()) {
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".soundest-form-background-image-close-holder > a")).click();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Popup is not shown");
        }
    }
    
    public void monitors(){
        WebElement monitors = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".row.categories-big >div:nth-child(1)"));
        monitors.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: _..I want test to continue in same window after first method ends.._ then why haven't you combined both the tests into a single test?

Comment: are you using xml file to run the suite?

Answer (score 0):

Marking the second test as `@Test` makes sense, if you think it's a separate thing to test. I understand wanting to pick up where the first left off and not wanting any test to get too large. Then you may want to explore skipping subsequent tests after an earlier one fails (or how to adapt to not being where you think you are).

What are you bumping into, though, is that your `@BeforeMethod` runs before each test. That is why the second test, when marked as a test, is staring in a new window. If you want to get setup and get that url once at the beginning, make it `@BeforeClass` instead (and similarly `@AfterClass` for totally closing up).

Answer (score 0):

use `@BeforeClass` to initiate the browser
use `@AfterClass` to quit the driver

Answer (score 0):

Each annotation had its own meaning, definition and functionality.

**@BeforeMethod**
The `@BeforeMethod` annotated method will be invoked before the execution of each test method. In your case, it will be going to execute before each test method ie. `mainPage()` and `monitors()`. And the same reason why the other test will be runnning in a new window or in the new session.

> **There is two solutions or annotation to solve your problem and by replacing the @BeforeMethod with them you can achieve the desired result:**

**@BeforeClass:** The `@BeforeClass` annotated method runs before the execution of the first test methods in a current class.

**@BeforeTest:** The method which comes under the `@BeforeTest` annotation will be executed first before any test belonging to that folder.

you can also use priority on `@Test` annoted method to set the sequence and can also use `@AfterMethod` annotation to take screenshots for each failure test case.

**Complete Fix Code:**

```
public class comtradeShop {

    WebDriver driver;
    String URL = "https://www.ctshop.rs/";

    @BeforeClass
    public void init() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver_91.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(URL);
    }



    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void mainPage() throws InterruptedException {
        WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".am-opener.sharkskin-collapse"));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sharkskin-megamenu.megamenu-v.megamenu-am>li:nth-child(6)")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement popup = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".soundest-form-background-image-wrapper"));
        if (popup.isDisplayed()) {
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".soundest-form-background-image-close-holder > a")).click();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Popup is not shown");
        }
    }
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void monitors(){
        WebElement monitors = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".row.categories-big >div:nth-child(1)"));
        monitors.click();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void takeScreenshot(ITestResult testResult) {
        if (testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE){
            //TAKE SCREENSHOTT ON FAILURE
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void quit(){
        if(driver!=null)
            driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I really appreciate your effort

Comment: If you satisfied with my answer, can you please accept it? :)